# Elasticsearch error resource_already_exists_exception when index doesn't exist for sure

Tags: elasticsearch, nestjs

I use random index name for new indices:

```
async import_index(alias_name, mappings, loadFn) {
    const index = `${alias_name}_${+new Date()}`
    console.log('creating new index: ', index)
    await this.esService.indices.create({
        index: index,
        body: {
            "settings": this.index_settings(),
            "mappings": mappings
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log('index created: ', index)
    }).catch(async (err) => {
        console.error(alias_name, ": creating new index", JSON.stringify(err.meta, null, 2))
        throw err
    });
```

I believe an index with this name cannot exist, but ES returns me this error

```
"error": {
      "root_cause": [
        {
          "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
          "reason": "index [brands_1637707367610/bvY5O_NjTm6mU3nQVx7QiA] already exists",
          "index_uuid": "bvY5O_NjTm6mU3nQVx7QiA",
          "index": "brands_1637707367610"
        }
      ],
      "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
      "reason": "index [brands_1637707367610/bvY5O_NjTm6mU3nQVx7QiA] already exists",
      "index_uuid": "bvY5O_NjTm6mU3nQVx7QiA",
      "index": "brands_1637707367610"
    },
    "status": 400
  }
```

ES installed in k8s using bitnami helm chart, 3 master nodes running. Client is connected to master service url. My thoughts: client sends a request to all nodes at the same time, but i cannot prove it.

plz help

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. How did you fix it?

Comment: I increased memory heap for container and it started work well.

Comment: Increasing memory heap probably made the operation perform faster. But this is dependent on the overall load of the cluster. Another way fine tuning this is configuring client and server timeouts. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced same error with the python client. But from what i see the javascript client is written in similar way.

There is a [retry](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/v7.17.0/lib/Transport.js#L224) option in the client.

Most likely this is set to true in your case (can be reconfigured). Then you pass a large mapping to `this.esService.indices.create`. The operation takes too long, times out, then a retry happens, but the index was created on the cluster.

You need to send a larger timeout to elasticsearch index create api (default 30s). And also set the same timeout  for the http connection.

Those are 2 separate settings:

1. Client http connection requestTimeout . Default: 30s

   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/v7.17.0/lib/Transport.js#L435

   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/7.17/basic-config.html
2. Serverside timeout via Create Index API. Default: 30s
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/indices-create-index.html

```
this.esService = new Client({
  // ....
  maxRetries: 5,
  requestTimeout: 60000 // time in  ms
})

// ....

tnis.esService.indices.create({
  index: index,
  body: {
    "settings": this.index_settings(),
     "mappings": mappings
  }, 
  timeout: "60s" // elasticsearch timestring
})
```